# Fourier transform of a tempered distribution : why a link with classical Fourier transform?

Tags: fourier-transform, distribution-theory

Fourier transform ($F$) of tempered distribution $\operatorname{sinc}$ is tempered distribution $\operatorname{Rect}$.

Does it mean that tempered distributions $F(\operatorname{sinc})$  and $\operatorname{Rect}$ behave the same as far as integration against Schwartz functions goes?

If so, how the latter (intuitively) proves that the Fourier transform (not in the sense of distributions) of $\operatorname{sinc}$ is indeed $\operatorname{Rect}$?

**In other words : how does this prove that Fourier transform of $\operatorname{sinc}$ in the sense of distribution is Fourier transform of $\operatorname{sinc}$ in the sense of functions?**

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question: yes, when you say that two distributions are equal you mean that they behave the same when integrated against test functions.

To show that the Fourier transform of $\operatorname{sinc}$ is $\operatorname{rect}$, I would actually go the other way around: take the Fourier transform of $\operatorname{rect}$.  It's a very basic one to calculate and will yield $\operatorname{sinc}$.  Then note that $\mathcal{F}^2(f) = \tilde{f}$, where $\tilde{f} = f(-x)$.  But both $\operatorname{rect}$ and $\operatorname{sinc}$ are symmetric with respect to this reflection, thus you have your desired result.

Comment: Thanks, I get this, however how does F(sinc) = Rect in the sense of distributions proves that Fourier transform of sinc is Rect in the sense of functions ?

Comment: Hmm, okay I apologize I didn't quite understand your question.  Well by definition for a tempered distribution $T$ then we define $(\mathcal{F}T)(f) = T(\mathcal{F}f)$ for $f$ a test function.  So we'd need to use that $rect(f) = sinc(\mathcal{F}f)$ to then derive $\mathcal{F}sinc = rect$ as functions.  But unfortunately I'm not quite sure how you define $rect$ and $sinc$ as distributions. . .

Comment: Aren't they defined as their integration against $f$ over $\mathbb{R}$ ? Rect is indeed the correct spectrum of sinc, so the equality must somehow be true in the sense of functions ? But how to get from distribution equality to associated functions equality ?

Comment: Yes, I believe that works.  I thought perhaps you were using the relationship $sinc$ can have to the dirac distribution (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function#Relationship_to_the_Dirac_delta_distribution).  It's actually a very interesting question you ask, I'll continue to think on it.

Answer (score 0):

- Do you mean the Fourier transform of $sinc$ in $L^2$ sense or in pointwise sense ie. the improper Riemann integrals $\int_{-\infty}^\infty sinc(x)e^{-2i\pi \xi x}dx$ ?
- The Fourier transform of $sinc$ in the sense of distributions (call it $T$) tells us $\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty sinc(x) e^{-2i\pi \xi x} e^{-\pi x^2/n^2}dx \tag{1}$

  not the same as the improper Riemann integral (well it is the same for $|\xi|\ne 1/2$ but it needs a proof specific to $sinc$)
- $(1)$ gives the Fourier transform of $sinc$ in $L^2$ sense as $\lim_{n\to \infty} T \ast ne^{-\pi n^2 x^2}$, limit in $L^2$ sense, since $T$ is the distribution $rect$ then it is $\lim_{n\to \infty} rect \ast ne^{-\pi n^2 x^2}=rect$, limit in $L^2$ sense.

Comment: Thanks. I was talking about $\int_{-\infty}^\infty sinc(x)e^{-2i\pi s x}dx$ (I don't know about the limit you describe, having more engineering rather than mathematical background^^) : How come this expression can somehow be equal to the Fourier transform of its associated distribution ? What is the link between Fourier transform of a function and Fourier transform of its associated distribution ? I'm glad I can have Fourier transform of distribution associated with sinc, but why does this also gives me the true spectrum of function sinc ?

Comment: $sinc$ is not $L^1$ so $\int_{-\infty}^\infty sinc(x)e^{-2i\pi \xi x}dx$ is not a natural thing to look at. Prove that for $|\xi|\ne 1/2$ this improper integral converges and is equal to $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty sinc(x) e^{-2i\pi \xi x} e^{-\pi x^2/n^2}dx$$
The latter is $$=\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty T(y)n e^{-\pi (y-\xi)^2 n^2}dy$$ by definition of the Fourier transform in the sense of distributions and our knowledge of the Gaussians. So it is $$=\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty rect(y)n e^{-\pi (y-\xi)^2 n^2}dy=rect(\xi)$$

Comment: What is $T(y)$ in the second line ? How do you go from functions to distributions in this explanation ? If I understand correctly, it has to do with approximating a function of infinite support with function of compact support (by multiplying by a gaussian) ?